# Repelling Random elements on a torus

Tags: materials, experimental-features

In his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5ungDgFNc&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&index=10) the Blender guru show how to create random sprinkles on the top of the donut.
I would like to know if there is a feature of Blender, which takes e.g. a real number
in the interval [-1,1] with the meaning that with number 0 the random sprinkles slightly touch
one another, with 1  they are repelled and with -1 they are fused. If this is not possible in the current Blender version, where can I ask for this new feature to become a reality ?